# How to make robot movement in rviz with moveit smoother?

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Is there a possibility to make the robot movement in rviz smoother?
As you can see in the video, the planned path is relatively smooth, but the simulated movement of the robot is lagging:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2yPOtkc84M&feature=youtu.be

I created the moveit config of the robot by myself with the moveit setup assistant.

I am using kinetic with rviz version 1.12.16.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307723/how-to-make-robot-movement-in-rviz-with-moveit-smoother?/) by [boandlgrama](https://answers.ros.org/users/38401/boandlgrama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution is to increse the parameter '*rate*' for the *joint_state_publisher*.
The default is only 10 Hz.

---

Originally posted by [boandlgrama](https://answers.ros.org/users/38401/boandlgrama/) with karma: 76 on 2018-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-04-01**:
Which you do by adding `<param name="rate" value="100"/>` to the `joint_state_publisher` call in your `demo.launch` file.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-04-01**:
I *thought* this would fix it, but actually it isn't very smooth, still. There may be another parameter to tweak.

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2020-04-02**:
The overall resolution of MoveIt's fake controller&joint_state_controller is not overwhelming from my experience. I would recommend using https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/moveit_sim_controller , the underlying https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/ros_control_boilerplate/blob/melodic-devel/CMakeLists.txt#L86 or any other ros_control stub.

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2021-02-15**:
doesn't work
"rostopic hz /joint_states" increased but angles update rate is 10hz